# Enumerate map variable using null_resource and triggers

Tags: enumeration, terraform

I'm trying to enumerate map variable using `null_resource` with `triggers` and use the result of this enumeration in another resource.

This works:

```
resource "null_resource" "dummy" {
  count = "${length(var.file_map)}"

  triggers {
    filename = "${element(keys(var.file_map), count.index)}"
    content = "${var.file_map[element(keys(var.file_map), count.index)]}"
  }
}

variable "file_map" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    "foo.txt" = "foo"
    "bar.txt" = "bar"
  }
}
```

Output:

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  + null_resource.dummy[0]
      id:                <computed>
      triggers.%:        "2"
      triggers.content:  "bar"
      triggers.filename: "bar.txt"

  + null_resource.dummy[1]
      id:                <computed>
      triggers.%:        "2"
      triggers.content:  "foo"
      triggers.filename: "foo.txt"


Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

But when I try to use the result of enumeration in the another resource it fails:

```
resource "local_file" "some_files" {
  content = "${null_resource.dummy.triggers.content}"
  filename = "${null_resource.dummy.triggers.filename}"
}

resource "null_resource" "dummy" {
  count = "${length(var.file_map)}"

  triggers {
    filename = "${element(keys(var.file_map), count.index)}"
    content = "${var.file_map[element(keys(var.file_map), count.index)]}"
  }
}

variable "file_map" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    "foo.txt" = "foo"
    "bar.txt" = "bar"
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* local_file.some_files: 1 error(s) occurred:

* local_file.some_files: Resource 'null_resource.dummy' not found for variable
                         'null_resource.dummy.triggers.content'
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar usage of `element` in resource `null_resource`, you need to do the same in `local_file`.

```
resource "local_file" "some_files" {
  count = "${length(var.file_map)}"

  content = "${element(null_resource.dummy.*.triggers.content, count.index)}"
  filename = "${element(null_resource.dummy.*.triggers.filename, count.index)}"
}

resource "null_resource" "dummy" {
  count = "${length(var.file_map)}"

  triggers {
    filename = "${element(keys(var.file_map), count.index)}"
    content = "${var.file_map[element(keys(var.file_map), count.index)]}"
  }
}

variable "file_map" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    "foo.txt" = "foo"
    "bar.txt" = "bar"
  }
}
```

After run `terraform apply`, it generates two files

```
$ cat bar.txt
bar
$ cat foo.txt
foo
```

If you want to know more, `cat terraform.tfstate` will give you details about how this works.

Comment: Wow, just wow. Thank you so much. I've been trying to use [splat hack](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11566#issuecomment-289417805) but failed. Now it all makes sense.